# Let $M = \frac{1}{2}(A + {A^T})$ be real symmetric nonnegative matrix. Why does $\rho (A) \le {\lambda _{\max }}(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A \in  M_n$ be nonnegative, and consider the real symmetric nonnegative matrix
$M = \frac{1}{2}(A + {A^T})$.

Why does $\rho (A) \le {\lambda _{\max }}(M)$?

Comment: This is a special case of Ky Fan's result, which says the real parts of the eignevalues of $A$ are majorized by the eigenvalues of $M$; see [K. Fan, Maximal properties and inequalities for the eigenvalues of completely continuous operators, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA, 37 (1951), pp. 760–766].